# Can we define multiple workflow rules

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am creating a pipeline with two request parameters.
Sample script as given below:

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
   - download
   - execute
variables:
  # Input variables
  BRANCH_REFERENCE:
    value: ""
    description: "This variable will hold value for Branch Reference"
  RELEASE_TYPE:
    value: ""
    description: "Release Type"  
  RUNNER_TAG: "wave"
  TEST_VAR: "TEST"

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $BRANCH_REFERENCE == "dev"
      variables:
        RUNNER_TAG: "wave-dev"
      when: always
    - if: $BRANCH_REFERENCE == "prd"
      variables:
        RUNNER_TAG: "wave-prd"  
    - if: $RELEASE_TYPE == "pplus"
      variables:
        TEST_VAR: "product_plus.tar.gz"
      when: always
    - if: $RELEASE_TYPE == "pmod"
      variables:
        TEST_VAR: "product.tar.gz"
      when: always  
    - when: always

download-job:   
  stage: download    
  script:
    - echo "Download Stage Starts"
    - echo ${TEST_VAR}
    - echo ${RUNNER_TAG}
    - echo "Download Stage Ends"
    
  tags:
    - $RUNNER_TAG
execute-job:   
  stage: execute    
  script:
    - echo "Execute Stage Starts"
    - echo ${TEST_VAR}
    - echo ${RUNNER_TAG}
    - echo "Execute Stage Ends"
    
  tags:
    - $RUNNER_TAG
```

While executing the pipeline I have passing 2 input parameters. Based on the input parameters I have to set some variable values.

For that I have tried to use workflow rules but it is not working as per my requirement.

e.g. Below are the input parameters

```
BRANCH_REFERENCE = dev
RELEASE_TYPE = pplus
```

so for this case the expected value of the **RUNNER_TAG** should set to “**wave-dev**” and **TEST_VAR** to “**product_plus.tar.gz**”.

But it is setting value for **RUNNER_TAG** to “**wave-dev**” and **TEST_VAR** to "TEST", because first if condition from workflow rules got satisfied and rest of the if conditions got skipped.

So, is it possible to use Workflow rules for such scenarios ? If no, then is there any another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, `workflow:rules` will stop evaluation at the first rule match, meaning that, at most, one `rules:variables:` applies.

For your situation, you *really* only need to set the variable used for the runner tag in `tags:`. Everything else can be handled at runtime. In other words: your other variables can also just be set directly in the job that utilizes the synthesized variables.

In this case, your logic required for setting `RUNNER_TAG` can be expressed using `workflow:rules:`, So you could do something like:

```yaml
variables:
  # Input variables
  BRANCH_REFERENCE:
    value: ""
    description: "This variable will hold value for Branch Reference"
  RELEASE_TYPE:
    value: ""
    description: "Release Type"  
  TEST_VAR: "TEST"
  RUNNER_TAG: 
    value: "wave-$BRANCH_REFERENCE"
    expand: true
workflow:
  rules:
   - if: $BRANCH_REFERENCE != "dev" && $BRANCH_REFERENCE != "prd"
     variables:
       RUNNER_TAG: "wave"
   - when: always

before_script: # set all variables at the start of each job
  - |
    if [[ "$RELEASE_TYPE" == "pmod" ]]; then
        export TEST_VAR="product.tar.gz"
    fi
    # ...etc
```

---

If you cannot express the required logic for the runner tag or other variables using `workflow:rules:`, generally, the easiest thing for complex rules involving many variables would be to use a [dotenv artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv) to set variables for subsequent jobs. Then you can implement the logic of setting variables however you would like.

This will also work for setting variables used in `tags:`.

```yaml
set-variables:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "dev" ]]; then echo "RUNNER_TAG=wave-dev" >> vars.env; fi
    - if [[ "$RELEASE_TYPE" == "pplus" ]]; then echo "TEST_VAR=product_plus.tar.gz" >> vars.env; fi
    # etc...
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: vars.env

job:
  script:
    - echo $CI_RUNNER_TAGS
    - echo $TEST_VAR
  tags:
    - $RUNNER_TAG
```

However, this will not work if the variables you want to set need to be evaluated in a job `rules:` -- since rules are evaluated at the time of pipeline creation.

---

Yet another workaround for the limitations of `workflow:rules:` is to use `include:rules:` and *every* include rule is evaluated individually. You can use this to [conditionally include yml files](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-rules-with-include) that declare additional variables that will be merged with your configuration.

This will work, even for setting variables used for job `rules:` since includes are processed at pipeline creation time.

Just make sure you orient these in the order of precedence you want and be aware of [how `include:` configurations are merged](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#merge-method-for-include).

```yaml
variables:
  BRANCH_REFERENCE: ""

include:
  - local: ./default-variables.yml

  - local: ./dev-variables.yml
    rules:
      - if: $BRANCH_REFERENCE == "dev"

  - local: ./prod-variables.yml
    rules:
      - if: $BRANCH_REFERENCE == "prd"

  - local: ./pplus-variables.yml
    rules:
      - if: $RELEASE_TYPE == "pplus"

  - local: ./pmod-variables.yml
    rules:
      - if: $RELEASE_TYPE == "pmod"
  # etc...
```